# MFC dialog borders

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I am programming in C++ using MFC.

I have two dialogs:

1. One with a WS_POPUP style intended to be a modal dialog
2. The other one with a WS_CHILD style intended to be a modeless dialog

Those (WS_POPUP and WS_CHILD) are the only changing styles between the two dialogs. I'm under windows 8.1 and **the problem is that I obtain a different border (decorator) running the two dialogs. I would like to have an identical border for both the dialogs** (specifically, the border of the first image above),
how can I do this?

Here are the images (I cannot post them directly due to my "low-reputation" ;) ):

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYj1q.png "Dialog 1"
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bswY7.png "Dialog 2"

Comment: Is your problem that one dialog has a caption and the other doesn't?

Comment: `WS_CHILD` indicates a child window. A (modeless) dialog can have an owner or be unowned, but it will never be a child window. What did you hope to achieve by setting the `WS_CHILD` window style?

Comment: `WS_CHILD` implies that you are going to embed the dialog inside another dialog/window. Is this your intent?

Comment: @IInspectable @ user1793036 it is a "CHILD" dialog because it has to remain, in the modeless style, inside another window, so that moving the "parent" one will result in a move of the inside dialog. And this is working correctly. I just would like to have the same borders.

@ rrirower the problem is the difference of the borders.